# how to define variable in a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript

When I define inside my component in angular the instance variable like that:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', //template: ``
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Welcome';
  nombre1 : number;
 
  
}
```

I have a red line below `nombre1`.
The error is :

```
Property 'nombre1' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(256
```

Can someone please tell me where is my error.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What's the TS compiler error message associated with the red line? The syntax is fine.

Comment: @seesharper check please the updated post

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the fact that you have declared your field as not being able to accept `undefined`, but you have not supplied a non-undefined value to it.

Either make the field able to accept undefined...

```
nombre1: number | undefined;
// or: nombre1?: number;
```

...or supply the default value:

```
nombre1: number = 0;
// or: assign it in constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered with this many times.
And i believe if you are using Visual studio code you will get hints on what to do.

What i normally do is add some initializer or a exclamation just after the variable name.
As in your code it would be as follows :

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', //template: ``
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'Welcome';
  nombre1!: number;  
}
```

**Note:** You have to specify what datatype you are dealing with.
Also if you dont want to give any value as initializer just use ! right after the variable name as shown.

Hope the issue is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use = instead :

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title= 'Hola ';
  nombre= 'john';
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<hello title="{{ title }}" nombre="{{ nombre}}"></hello>
```

hello.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'hello',
      template: `<h1>{{title}} {{nombre}}! </h1>`,
      styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
    })
    export class HelloComponent  {
      @Input() title: string;
      @Input() nombre: string;
    }
```